# How to send integer value to js in cordova 3.x plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have a native project that has a view controller implementing corebluetooth functionality.

```
@interface HRMViewController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
@end
```

I'm trying to convert that to cordova plugin. Is it valid to write as follows.

```
@interface BLEPlugin : CDVPlugin <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
@end
```

Without including the implementation statement the build fails. Is the above code correct from cordova plugin perspective?

Could you provide an example where the plugin methods sends an integer value to js? The integer value is saved in a property in header file as

```
@property (assign) uint16_t rate;
```

Should I include frameworks required in config.xml like

```
<framework src="CoreBluetooth.framework" weak="true" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To send an integer to js, from a plugin result, you can do it like this:

```
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult: [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsInt:rate]  callbackId:command.callbackId];
```